# Retrieving RTF text from Microsoft EWS

Tags: outlook, rtf, exchangewebservices

Would it be possible to get RTF content using Exchange Web Services.

Ews property set only allows body type HTML or plain text.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get it from an existing message, in RTF format? Or are you creating a new message and want to put RTF content into the new message?

Comment: @MimiGentz, I am trying to get an existing message.

Comment: There's an extended property for the compressed RTF. I haven't tested this on an RTF message, but I think that if you include the extended property definition in your property set, you should be able to retrieve the content of that property.

`ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagRtfCompressed = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1009, MapiPropertyType.Binary);
    PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.Subject, PidTagRtfCompressed);
    EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, ItemId, propSet);`

Comment: Did you get a chance to try that?

Comment: @MimiGentz - Yes. Unfortunately it didn't work.var PidTagRtfCompressed = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1009, MapiPropertyType.Binary);var propertySet=new PropertySet(new PropertyDefinitionBase[] {  ItemSchema.MimeContent, ItemSchema.Subject, PidTagRtfCompressed });message.Load(propertySet); Saved mimecontent to eml and when I looked at the content there is no RTF content. Only HTML and plain text. Tried to load the eml with Outlook, still displaying HTML.

Comment: There's a difference between getting the RTF of a message and what Outlook would show. When you look at the SOAP returned by the GetItemResponse (the response to the Load method) is there anything returned in the RTF element?

Comment: Saved mime content from EWS to disk and looked at the eml using notepad. Didn't find any RTF data. I will look at the SOAP and let you know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MimiGentz, I have saved the response mimecontent to disk and opened with Notepad. It didn't got any RTF content.

Comment: @MimiGentz, thanks for your input. I was looking at the wrong place. I suppose to get the object from ExtendedProperties. Now I can see some data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the PidTagRtfCompressed property to get create an extended property definition, and then add the extended property definition to your property set, then get the item using that property set. The response will contain the RTF data.

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagRtfCompressed = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1009, MapiPropertyType.Binary);     
PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.Subject, PidTagRtfCompressed);     
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, ItemId, propSet);
```

Comment: Mimi, what does the returned byte array actually contain? I'm not sure how to get the actual RTF text from it.

Comment: I haven't worked with this in a long while, but the byte array contains the base-64 compressed RTF body. The compression and decompression algorithm is defined in the MS-OXRTFCP protocol document, and there's a decompression example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee219303(v=exchg.80).aspx. You literally have to decipher it bit by bit.